# Почему Task, отдельно созданный через конструктор и отложено выполненный, игнорирует оператор await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Обнаружил странное. Если создаю Task таким образом

```
var task = new Task(async action);
task.Start();
```

то при вызове любого асинхронного метода (`await Task.Delay()`, `await new WebClient().DownloadStringAsync()`, etc.) игнорируется оператор `await` и код сразу же возвращается к основному потоку.

Если же Task конструирую рекомендуемым во всех статьях способом (через `Task.Run(async action)`), то всё работает, как ожидается.

Пример кода, иллюстрирующий проблему:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // way1 - it's working
        var goodTask = Task.Run(async () => await ProblemMethod("goodTask"));
        await goodTask;
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} :: {nameof(goodTask)} is finished.");

        // way2 - it fails without any exceptions on line with GetRequestStreamAsync
        var poorTask = new Task(async () => await ProblemMethod("poorTask"));
        poorTask.Start();
        await poorTask;
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} :: {nameof(poorTask)} is finished.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task ProblemMethod(string taskName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{taskName} :: {DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} :: It's a first line.");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"{taskName} :: {DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} :: It's a last line.");
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится:

```
goodTask :: 18:52:50 :: It's a first line.
goodTask :: 18:52:52 :: It's a last line.
18:52:52 :: goodTask is finished.
poorTask :: 18:52:52 :: It's a first line.
18:52:52 :: poorTask is finished.
poorTask :: 18:52:54 :: It's a last line.
```

Почему такое странное поведение во втором случае ("it's a last line" выводится уже после возвращения в основной поток? Оператор await ведь присутствует...

P.S. Да, я в курсе, что рекомендуемый способ работы с тасками в TAP - это сразу же запускать их при конструировании (через `Task.Run` или `Task.Factory.StartNew`), но как следует поступать, если необходимо отделять конструирование тасков от команды на их исполнение, т.е., если надо реализовать их отложенное выполнение?

Comment: `new Task(async () => await ProblemMethod("poorTask"))` -> `new Task<Task>(async () => await ProblemMethod("poorTask"))`, `await poorTask` -> `await poorTask.Unwrap()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что конструктор `new Task()` принимает только `Action` и `Action<T>` с разными комбинациями токена отмены, стейта и т.д, но нет перегрузки, принимающей `Func<Task>` или `Func<T, Task>`
чтобы можно было дождаться переданной асинхронной лямбды. В то время как Task.Run имеет такую перегрузку.

Таким образом - у вас возникает классическая проблема ожидания `async void`.

Если мы сделаем `var result = await poorTask;` то фактически мы получим void и ошибку компиляции.
Для того чтобы дождаться внутренней задачи, обычно нужно сделать Unwrap или добавить еще один await, но в данном случае мы получаем void и дождаться внутренней задачи не можем.

Как описал в комментарии @PetSerAl нужно использовать generic версию `Task<Task>` чтобы иметь возможность дождаться внутренней задачи.